# Android Gridview - Element position changing Randomly when scrolling

Tags: android, android-gridview

I have a `GridView` which have 10 rows and 7 columns. The elements in the `GridView` are not in a unique form that is one row contains 7 element, one row has only 4 or 5 elements, etc. Now I have created the `GridView` with full elements that is 70 elements. Now I want to hide some elements in the `GridView`. I have tried by setting visibility of the `ImageView` and `TextView` to `View.INVISIBLE`. It works but when we scroll the `GridView` it randomly changes.

1. [This is exactly what I wanted](https://plus.google.com/photos/103076464130813961822/albums/5875103733171068625/5875103737979749602?hl=en&utm_source=lmnavbr&utm_medium=embd&utm_campaign=lrnmre&rtsl=1)
2. One more problem is that each row contains a title not to each element.

What I have to do? I am new to Android.

Code:

```
@Override
public int getCount() 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return listFlag.size();
}

@Override
public String getItem(int position)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return listCountry.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

public static class ViewHolder
{
    public ImageView imgViewFlag;
    public TextView txtViewTitle;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ViewHolder view;
    LayoutInflater inflator = activity.getLayoutInflater();
    int childSize = parent.getChildCount();
    if(convertView==null)
    {
        view = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.gridview_row, null);
        view.txtViewTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        view.imgViewFlag  = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        convertView.setTag(view);
    }
    else
    {
        view = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    if(position==64||position==57||position==58||position==59||position==50||position==23||position==16||position==17||position==9||position==10||position==12||position==1||position==2||position==8)
    {
        view.txtViewTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        view.imgViewFlag.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    view.txtViewTitle.setText(listCountry.get(position));
    view.imgViewFlag.setImageResource(listFlag.get(position));

    return convertView;
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with the setVisibility calls in the code.

```
if(position==64||position==57||position==58||position==59||position==50||position==23||position==16||position==17||position==9||position==10||position==12||position==1||position==2||position==8)
{
    view.txtViewTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    view.imgViewFlag.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

You set them to GONE when you don't need them but you don't set them to VISIBLE when you need them. Once you set the to GONE, the same cells will be reused when you scroll. At that point, if you don't set them to VISIBLE, them will never show up.

```
if(position==64||position==57||position==58||position==59||position==50||position==23||position==16||position==17||position==9||position==10||position==12||position==1||position==2||position==8)
{
    view.txtViewTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    view.imgViewFlag.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else {
    view.txtViewTitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    view.imgViewFlag.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

To address your second part about the title, you can add a TextView for the title to each cell but only set its visibility to VISIBLE if it is the first item in the row. That way you won't have to make too much custom code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey it works :) thank you so much. then wot about the title.?

Comment: I edited the answer to include the comment about the title. Please accept the answer if it works :)

Comment: the problem is that i have a long title on a row which have 7 elements the title overlapping the second element thats why i couldnt see the full title.:(

Comment: One thing you can try is to have a ListView with each cell (which spans the whole width) containing 7 ImageViews and 1 TextView for the title. You can set visibility just like in GridView to any of the ImageViews and the title TextView will span the whole width thus preventing any truncation.

Comment: i didnt get you . can you please  provide me one example.?

Comment: what is span. ? I am not familiar with spans.

Comment: Hey i need to use grid views because i need to select the elements.And the user can only select one element from the row. not more than one element.